# Spring get instance of AuthenticationManager complicated since WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Spring recently deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which does seem as not the smartest move, given that the new way is extremely poorly documented and WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter was basically omnipresent. Now I tried to add a custom Filter to the Security Filterchain, which was easy before but does seem to bring some trouble now.

I found a workaround, but it feels extremely overcomplicated and is not even remotely documented anywhere. If I use a code similar the the one below, I do get an instance of the authenticationManager and everything works fine.

```
 public static class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                    http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
            AuthFilter filter = new AuthFilter();
            filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
            System.out.println("Manager is" + authenticationManager); 
// prints Manager is ProviderManager as expected

            http.addFilter(filter);

        }


        public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
            return new MyCustomDsl();
        }
    }
```

If I move the exact same code out of this hopefully unnecessary construct directly into the part below, then it does not work. The error I get is authentication Manager is null. I do assume it is related to when which Bean is created, but can't seem to find a cleaner solution than the one above.

```
 @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        AuthFilter filter = new AuthFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        System.out.println("Manager is" + authenticationManager);
// says: Manager is null



//more config

}
```

I might add, there is another strange behavior. I tried to build an instance like this (which seems intuitive).

```
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
```

However, this does not work as well. What is more strange: If I say build() - it errors with "already built".
If I try to get it (since it seemingly was already build) - I get an null object. There is even a getorbuild method, but you guessed it, that errors as well. Quite strange to me.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can pin me in the right direction to get this clean and concise. Thanks.

Comment: Post your full security configuration class this is not reproducible with the small amount of code and no context you only need to do strange things if the rest of the code is strange

Comment: @Toerktumlare the solution below is spot on.

Comment: Well he did some assumptions and he was right, i usually dont want to make assumptions because people asking questions can be very rude when the answer is not 100% right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In this post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) it says:

> To create an AuthenticationManager that is available to the entire application you can simply register the AuthenticationManager as a @Bean.

With that said, if you need to use an `AuthenticationManager` somewhere, you need to expose it as a bean. I'll assume that you already have an `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` beans. You can do it like this:

```java
@Bean
AuthenticationManager myAuthenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    return provider::authenticate;
}
```

And now just inject it into your `SecurityFilterChain` method:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Be aware that the `AuthenticationProvider` interface [will be deprecated soon](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11428), stay tuned in the release notes for the future versions.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcus, that was extremely helpful and spot on what I was looking for basically everywhere. Can you point me in a direction where you guys have more resources / documented this solution somewhere?

Comment: Reading the post that I referenced is a good start. You can also read the [Authentication Architecture chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html) in the reference docs. It is important to know what interfaces Spring Security uses and how it configures them.

Comment: The tests inside the Spring Security source code also have a lot of common setups that are useful for most applications

Comment: Thanks for the link. The post you mentioned was the first document I stumbled upon of course and while it did help, I never got around to add AuthenticationManager to the method signature .. didn't know that's enough for spring to pick it up. Thanks a lot.