# AuthenticationManager.authenticate() returns stackoverflow

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I'm trying to make a simple login system on my project, using Spring 3.1.1 and Spring Security 3.1.1 as well. Read on the documentation that we should not "extends WebSecurityAdapter" anymore and instead implement it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    RequestFilter requestFilter;

    /**
     * List with whitelisted endpoints.
     */
    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            // -- Swagger UI v2
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            // -- Swagger UI v3 (OpenAPI)
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            // other public endpoints of your API may be appended to this array
            "/users/register",
            "/users/login",
            "/plans/free-plan"
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterBefore(requestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

In this class I create an "AuthenticationManager" on the bean but when I try to use this on my service it gives an Stackoverflow error. My service:

```
@Service
public class UserService extends GenericService<User> {

    /**
     * Authentication Manager instance.
     */
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    /**
     * User Repository instance.
     */
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    /**
     * JWTUtils Instance.
     */
    private JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

    /**
     * Plan Service instance.
     */
    private PlanService planService;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserRepository userRepository,
                       JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils, PlanService planService) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
        this.planService = planService;
    }

    @Override
    protected GenericRepository getGenericRepository() {
        return userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected SearchPredicate<User> getSearchPredicate(String search) {
        return null;
    }

    /* Methods */

    /**
     * Method to login on Coupler API.
     *
     * @param jwtRequestDTO Login request DTO.
     * @return {@link JwtResponseDTO}. JWT Token with all the info.
     * @throws RestRequestException The API can throw an exception if it cannot find necessary data.
     */
    public JwtResponseDTO login(JwtRequestDTO jwtRequestDTO) throws RestRequestException {
        var userPassword = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRequestDTO.getEmail(), jwtRequestDTO.getPassword());
        // The error is here!
        var auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(userPassword);
        var token = jwtTokenUtils.generateToken(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getEmail());
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(jwtRequestDTO.getEmail())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RestRequestException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ErrorIndicator.FIM_ERROR_U01.getMessage()));
        return new JwtResponseDTO(token, user.getId());
    }
}
```

I'm not defining any other AuthenticationManager in my system and when I comment or remove the "@Bean" with the AuthenticationManager, it claims that my UserService requires a bean that was not provided and this beam is the AuthenticationManager.
The "RequestFilter" is my "extended OncePerRequestFilter" implementation, don't think the problem is there so I'll ignore it for the sake of keeping it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12343). You can publish the `AuthenticationManager` bean correctly to resolve it. For examples, see [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11926#issue-1392720412), [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037749/15835039) and the [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html#_publish_an_authenticationmanager_bean).

Please note that Spring Security has [built-in support for JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) as well, so you can avoid writing your own filter.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped A LOT! Now I just need to understand how to change the "UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build();" to the data I'm receiving from the endpoint...? I have no idea how to do that! I'll take a look and see what I can find! Thanks again!

Comment: The comment link includes an example.

Comment: [Password Storage](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/storage.html) in the reference docs also includes examples, as does the blog post. You're looking for `UserDetailsService`.

Comment: Hey it's me again. Sorry but I gave a little attention to the examples you mentioned but I couldn't find them. Looking for "UserDetailsService" I've found this example (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database) but didn't work. I'm using Spring Data JPA and the user (attribute named Email not Username) is already saved on the database, this RestController endpoint that I'm coding is the Login, should check if the Email and Password matches and generate a Token back, Am I doing it right? What should I look for?

Comment: @AlfredoMarin Please open a new question with the details of what you're trying to do and what you've tried. Comments aren't the best place to work through questions and issues.

Comment: Agreed! just created a new question! Thanks man! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534186/spring-security-3-userdetailsservice